# Devexpress Gridview Repository Editor Different Datasource For Each Row

Tags: gridview, repository, devexpress, datasource

![I want to change the datasource of a lookupedit repository when other lookupedit repository changed. I used EditValueChanged of lookup repository but when i changed the selection all rows affected with the new datasource... I want to change ony 1 rows datasource when the other lookup value changed... As seen in the pic above when i changed no1 column i want to change the datasource of no2 column when i changed no3 column i want to change no4 columns datasource. thanks in advance.][1]

http://www.teknonova.com/ss2.png

Answer (score 0):

Handle the GridView's ShownEditor event, grab the active editor object via the GridView.ActiveEditor property, and change its Properties.DataSource at that point. You can fetch the focused row and column via the GridView.FocusedRowHandle and GridView.FocusedColumn properties.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var v = sender as GridView;
    if (v.FocusedColumn.FieldName != "myField") return;
    var edit = v.ActiveEditor;
    var currentRow = v.GetRow(v.FocusedRowHandle) as MyDataRowType;
    if (currentRow.AnyProperty)
        edit.Properties.DataSource = .....;
}
```